# Modem can't be initialised after distro upgrade to 15.10

Tags: network-manager, usb-modem, zte

I used Kubuntu 15.04 and my ZTE modem worked. Since I upgraded to 15.10 via Muon, the modem does not work: I enter PIN and after that I get the message: "The modem could not be initialised."

I guess it is a problem with the network manager. Any hint where to look and how?